# How to call a javascript function after *ngIf render

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular2-routing

My app.component.html contains these code to display the slider.

```
 <div  class="slider-pro" id="slider" *ngIf="router.url == '/home'">
   <script type='text/javascript'>
      initSlider();
    </script>
   ...
 </div>
```

But it seem that the angular2 framework skip my javascript lines. My question is how to call a javascript function after *ngIf render DOM element. I tried call this function inside ngAfterViewInit(), but it doesn't worked. I need to run this function initSlider() to add onChange event.

Answer (score 1):

Call this function inside ngAfterViewChecked. This gets called after every check of component's view.

```
class MyComponent implements AfterViewChecked {
    ngAfterViewChecked() {
        //TODO - invoke here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks your suggestion, but if I do this, my javascript will execute n times. The on-change, or click event will execute n times as well. In addition, I have my own solution. Thanks